# Android Build Fails, Execution failed for task ':app:exponentPrebuildStep'

Tags: android, android-studio, react-native, expo

I’m encountering an issue when trying to build my detached Expo project in Android Studio. Was wondering if any else had encountered the same issue and had some insight on how to resolve it?

Here’s the error log:
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:exponentPrebuildStep'.

> Process 'command './.expo-source/android/detach-scripts/prepare-detached-build.sh'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

I am running a Linux OS, Ubuntu 16.04.